# Check is finish of async and await

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await

I am trying to understand the `async` and `await`.Now i want to apply `async` and `await` keyword in my current project.My process structure are:

```
//DataAccess 
Private List<Users> GetAllUsers()
{
   .... ;
   return List<Users>
}

//UI
List<Users> UserList=new List<Users>();
private async void Ok_ClickAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //I want to select all user ant assign to UserList but currently it not use.
    UserList=await BindUser();    
}

private async Task<List<Users>> BindUser()
{
  List<Users> model=await Task.Run(()=>GetAllUsers());
  return model;
}
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   //I want to use UserList here and want to validate process   
}
```

Problem is if i click save click button quickly,`UserList` count are `0`(Actually `UserList` record are over 100,000).So I want to check `BindUser()` process is finish or not before doing validation process in `Save_Click()`. Please let me known for best solution and help me to understand `async` and `await` keyword. Thanks.

Comment: Implement await async in GetAllUsers method and return Task<List<Users>> from there. List<Users> model=await GetAllUsers();

Comment: If you are using LINQ and EF , it will affect your performance because they are very slow with large database. I suggest you to use pagination and only fetch those records which you want.

Answer (score 3):

The question is not very clear, but if I understand you correctly then:

Instead of

```
//UI
List<Users> UserList=new List<Users>();
```

You could keep a reference to a Task that will get you the user list:

```
//UI
Task<List<Users>> users;
```

And then:

```
private async Task btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     if (users != null)
     {
          List<Users> userList  = await users;
          // Your validations etc.
     }
}
```

Clearly, this doesn't handle error cases, but will allow you to retrieve the user list using async/await.